# Why does my electric shower still have water coming out even though it's switched off?

Tags: shower

Water still comes out of the shower head even though it's switched off. Please help with a possible solution!!!

Comment: Did not know such a thing existed. Cool.

Answer (score 2):

I would think most likely the valve in the shower that controls the water flow has failed. It may be possible to replace the valve or you may end up having to replace the whole shower unit.

Follow-up questions:

What is the make and model of the electric shower unit?

What country are you in?